# Replace string in cloned jquery object

Tags: jquery, string, replace

in the following script I clone a new row form tfoot and append it to table tbody

```
<script>
$('#checklist-builder .add-row').click(function(){
    var new_row = $('#checklist-builder>tfoot>tr').clone();
    $('#checklist-builder>tbody').append(new_row);
});
</script>
```

cloned row is:

```
<tr>
  <td>${j}</td>
  <td>
    <input size="2" type="hidden" value="" name="WhoChecklistField[1][${j}][id]" id="WhoChecklistField_1_${j}_id">      <input size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" value="" name="WhoChecklistField[1][${j}][weight]" id="WhoChecklistField_1_${j}_weight">    </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="" name="WhoChecklistField[1][${j}][name]" id="WhoChecklistField_1_${j}_name">    </td>
  <td>
    <select size="1" name="WhoChecklistField[1][${j}][type]" id="WhoChecklistField_1_${j}_type">
      <option value="text">Text field</option>
      <option value="select">Select field</option>
      <option value="radio">Radio field</option>
      <option value="checkbox">Checkbox field</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

now I want replace `${j}` with `table size + 1`, how can I replace `${j}` in jquery cloned string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
new_row.html(function(i, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/\${j}/g, 'table_size');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P43mW/1/)**

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Akbari Why down vote? may I know? Only my code is working here. you have to put a \ before $

Comment: if there is ${j} on <tr> also, its not replacing that, how can we replace text on tr also?

Answer (score 2):

From my own problem i came up with below code that works also and maybe will help someone (full example)

```
$j('grab_object')
.clone()
.html(function(i, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/regular_expression/, change_found_expression_to_this);
}))
.appendTo('paste_object_here');
```

And You should recieve cloned and pasted object with changed part of its code. In my case I was changing `[nr]` with a number and my expression was like below

```
(...).replace(/\[nr\]/g, $j('#some_id').val().(...)
```

Also due to documentation remember that with `clone()` jQuery also copies attributes including `id` and this can cause some issues in further manipulation in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Before you `append` just do:

```
new_row.html(function(i, oldHtml){ return oldHtml.replace(/${j}/g, tSize) });
```

Comment: why down vote? I don't know. but you code will fail I think, see http://jsfiddle.net/P43mW/2/..

Comment: It not worked with ${j} but when I changed it to xxx worked, I want exactly work with ${j}, should I change your regx?